# deploying an ASP.NET 7.0 application using docker and virtual paths

Tags: asp.net, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to deploy an asp.net 7.0 application via docker. I use 2 containers. One is the application container and the other is an nginx container that sets up nginx as a reverse proxy. I have several other containerized applications successfully using the proxy by utilising the scheme https://hostname/appname
The application I am trying to host is set up to use the https://hostname/versionhandler url.
I have successfully set up the container for the app and the nginx configuration.
nginx config:

```
 location /versionhandler/ {
                proxy_pass http://versionhandler/;
}
```

Program.cs excerpt from the app:

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost
});
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{

    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();

}
else
{
    
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    var src = builder.Configuration.Sources.ToArray();
    var inf = "";
    foreach (var source in src)
    {
        inf += source+Environment.NewLine;
    }
    logger.LogInformation(inf);
    logger.LogInformation($"ConnectionString:{connectionString}");
    try
    {
        
        
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        if (context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
        {
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }
        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await ContextSeed.SeedRolesAsync(userManager, roleManager);
        await ContextSeed.SeedAdminAsync(userManager, roleManager);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
    }
}


//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UsePathBase("/versionhandler/");
app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles(
    new StaticFileOptions
    {
        RequestPath="/versionhandler"    
    }
    );


app.UseAuthorization();
//app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

The application is served, but the static files do not have a correct path,
for example in one of the views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css") />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("~/css/site.css") asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("~/VersionHandler.styles.css") asp-append-version="true" />
```

The urls are not expanded from tilde to /versionhandler
Also the urls for the controllers generated do not contain the /versionhandler prefix.
When run in IISExpress using the virtualpath /versionhandler locally the application works ok. I have checked configuration and I cannot find an answer to this.
The dockerfile I am using is:

```
#official asp.net image for 7.0
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
#EXPOSE 443/tcp

#official NET sdk
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["VersionHandler.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "VersionHandler.csproj"
COPY . .
COPY .git/ .git/
RUN dotnet build "VersionHandler.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

#PUBLISH THE BUILD
FROM build as publish
RUN dotnet publish "VersionHandler.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","VersionHandler.dll"]
```

I was expecting the app to work properly when dockerized but this does not seem to be the case.